Is it possible to change the point which is used to define the drop target in flutter?
When drag & drop is used the usually cursor and feedback widget has such look:

Where the arrow is a point for hit testing (sorry for bad image). But I would like to change the point fot hit testing thus the cursor and feedback look like

Is it possible somehow?

I mean visual representation of feedback widget and the point which is used for hit testing. I want to change it from defaullt left top to left bottom.
